# MFMessageComposeController Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i'm having a problem with my MFMessageComposeController. So, in my app every time you click on a button, a UIActionSheet appears and then you have to select if you want to make a call or send a message . But every time that i make a call, end it and return to my app, my MFMessageComposeController appears... where could the problem be ? here is the code if it helps

```
case 0 : {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"tel://011212"]];
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];            
}
case 1: {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];   
}





[[UIApplication sharedApplication ] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
MFMessageComposeViewController*controller =[[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

    controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Narucio bih Oryx Taxi na lokaciju ( %@ , %@ ) .\nNaruci! aplikacija", latitudePoint.text, longitudePoint.text];



    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"011888",nil];
    //controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate=self;
    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't see `MFMessageComposeViewController` in your code snippet.  Can you show more context?  Also do you intend that your `case` blocks  aren't terminated with a `break` statement?  Perhaps your intent is for the execution to flow through `case 0` to `case 1`.

Comment: @userDSafa: Please refer to my answer. That would help you.

Comment: MFMessageComposeViewController is in a void function, it's just called inside switch-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a break after each case in your switch statement.  Otherwise execution will fall through to the next case.

```
case 0 : {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"tel://011212"]];
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];  
    break;          
}
case 1: {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];  
    break; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't ended the switch statement's `case 0` so even if it executes the first case, it always goes into the second case too. The solution is using `break`:

```
case 0 : {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"tel://011212"]];
  [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];  
  break;          
}
case 1: {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];  
  break; 
}
```

Comment: And just one question, in my MFMessageComposeViewController, the status bar color or style is set as BlackOpaque... since i have 4 MFMessageComposeControllers, in the three of them the color is BlackOpaque, but not in the fourth.. the code was copy-paste that's why is confuses me..the code is in the question above..

Comment: You just need to keep references to your `MFMessageComposeViewController`s in your class declaration like msgController1, msgController2...and set the status bar color according to which is which.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `break;` after each case is completed, just to make sure that execution of the cases following the current case don't take place.

Try this code:

```
case 0 : {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"tel://011212"]];
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO]; 
    break;
}
case 1: {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    break;   
}
default:
    break;


    MFMessageComposeViewController*controller =[[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Narucio bih Oryx Taxi na lokaciju ( %@ , %@ ) .\nNaruci! aplikacija", latitudePoint.text, longitudePoint.text];



        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"011888",nil];
        //controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate=self;
        controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

Hope this helps you.